# Injecting JavaScript into page using Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Hi I'm trying to do a first project to play around with making a simple Chrome extension but I can't seem to get this code right.

I'm using manifest v3.

And all I'm really trying to do is inject a line of js into the web page. In this case I'm just trying to fill in the text field on chatgpt when I click a button. There seems to be a ton of ways to do this online and with manifest v3 it seems it had some changes to the method to do this.

I'm not sure if its just a permissions issue or that it now has to be injected using a separate file?

Manifest - Ignore the covid info example I used here.

```
{
    "name": "Covid-19 Stats UK",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "latest covid data of UK",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "author": "Sampurna Chapagain",
    "action":{
        "default_popup": "index.html",
        "default_title": "Latest Covid Report"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "scripting"
    ]

}
```

JS

```
document.getElementById("btnStart").addEventListener("click", automate);

function automate(){
    const step = "";
    document.getElementById("step-1").innerHTML = step;

    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, url: "https://chat.openai.com/*"}, function(tabs) {
        if (tabs.length > 0) { //you are on the specified domain.
            alert(""); //hits this

            //does not work
            chrome.scripting.executeScript(null,
                {code: "document.getElementById('prompt-textarea').value = 'new value';"}
             );

        }
      });
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>title</title>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <input type="text" id="step-1">
        <input type="button" id="btnStart">Start</button>
    </body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

</html>
```

I've tried several different ways and ways specified from manifest v3 but I'm new to Chrome extensions.

Comment: The syntax of executeScript in your code doesn't match the reality, probably due to the use of the hallucinatory ChatGPT. Please refer to the human-written examples for chrome.scripting.executeScript.